# AJAX function runs only once how do I reset this?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

**This question has been answered in the comments** :)

I hope I don't get any slack for this one. But I've been looking for hours and can't seem to find the solution.

I have a jQuery script that animates a div from offscreen to `50vw` and this all works great. I've then set-up a little script that first shows a loader and then the loader fades out and the content is visible. Using this code:

```
success: function(response) {

        $(".flyin-feestinfo").fadeIn(500, function() {
            $('.feestlocatie_loader i, .feestlocatie_loader p').delay(500).fadeOut(1500);
            $('.feestlocatie_loader').delay(1500).fadeOut(1500);
            $(".flyin-feestinfo").html(response);
        });
    }
```

This all works great, one time only. If I close the window and open the off screen div again. The previous data is still there and after a little while the new content is shown.

What I would like is to have the `loader` to show again and fadeout and then show the new content. Now I'm pretty new to this all and I don't know if I need an `if` or `else` statement in there to get this to work. Or that I need to clear / reset the div when closing?

Help would be much appreciated... Please let me know if you all need more info...

Comment: "close the window" does not mean close the browser/tab right? So where do you show the loader? Seems like you would show it when you make the call...

Comment: @jay I do not see where you `fadeIn()` the `.feestlocatie_loader` then I'm assuming once it disappeared then it won't come back again, no?

Comment: @epascarello currently "close" means pressing the `escape key` to make the div animate back `-900px`

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti Correct. I don't `fadeIn()` the `.feestlocatie_loader` it's just there. Do I have to fade it in? or use `.show()`

Comment: you could inspect your `.feestlocatie_loader` element in the debug tools while you are doing the ajax calls, if i'm right (as Adriano too), the element should be still there, but no visible. you could use `$('.feestlocatie_loader, .feestlocatie_loader i, .feestlocatie_loader p').show();` before launching your ajax call (EDIT: show or fadeIn just the same, depends if you want it to be animated)

Comment: Well think about it, you fade it out so it is now hidden.... If you want to see if again, than you need to reshow it...

Comment: @Kaddath @espascarello really... that was all... I've put `.show()` on all elements that where previously hidden (faded out) in the `click`-event and it works like a charm! Thanks a million! If you think about it its actually pretty simple :)